# How can I look through links in a div grid

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
def test_all_collections_open(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get("https://igavesti-ou.myshopify.com/")
    driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Meat").click()
    assert "Meat" in driver.title
    driver.find_element_by_link_text('Home').click()
    driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Fish").click()
    assert "Fish" in driver.title
    driver.find_element_by_link_text('Home').click()
    driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Spices").click()
    assert "Spices" in driver.title
    driver.find_element_by_link_text('Home').click()
    driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Ghee").click()
    assert "Ghee" in driver.title
    driver.find_element_by_link_text('Home').click()
    driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Vegetable").click()
    assert "Vegetable" in driver.title
    driver.find_element_by_link_text('Home').click()
    driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Frozen").click()
    assert "Frozen" in driver.title
    driver.find_element_by_link_text('Home').click()
    driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Rice").click()
    assert "Rice" in driver.title
    driver.find_element_by_link_text('Home').click()
    driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Sweets").click()
    assert "Sweets" in driver.title
```

I want to make a loop of this so each time it clicks on a collections link and verifies each page opens. I tried several ways, but it always clicks on the first link which is Meat. The above solution is an old school way but how I can implement it through a loop.

[This is the section how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7J0f.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This can be a solution:

```
def test_all_collections(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get("https://igavesti-ou.myshopify.com/")
    collections = ["Meat", "Fish", "Spices", "Ghee", "Vegetable", "Frozen", "Rice", "Sweets"]
    for collection_name in collections:
        driver.find_element_by_link_text('Home').click()
        driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text(x).click()
        assert collection_name in driver.title
```